# Docker TLS - How to create key on local machine

Tags: docker, ssl, openssl

**Pre knowledge:**

So I started using docker myself and installed it on my server and enabled TLS. I followed this tutorial: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/

This tutorial will eventually give you 6 files:

1. -r-------- **ca-key.pem**
2. -r--r--r-- **ca.pem**
3. -r--r--r-- **cert.pem**
4. -r-------- **key.pem**
5. -r--r--r-- **server-cert.pem**
6. -r-------- **server-key.pem**

The owner of these files is **root**. I copied the **ca.pem**, **cert.pem** and **key.pem**, I used them to connect from my local portainer instance. (Actually I only use **cert.pem** and **key.pem** since I only have client verification on)

**DOCKER HOST:**

```
{
  "hosts": [
    "unix:///var/run/docker.sock",
    "tcp://0.0.0.0:2376"
  ],
  "storage-driver": "overlay2",
  "tls": true,
  "tlscacert": "/etc/docker/certs/ca.pem",
  "tlscert": "/etc/docker/certs/server-cert.pem",
  "tlskey": "/etc/docker/certs/server-key.pem",
  "tlsverify": true
}
```

---

**My problem:**

The company where I work installed docker for me and enabled TLS, put all the **pem** files in a directory which I can access... Problem is, I cannot download the **key.pem** since the owner is root and I won't get access to it.

I can download the next files:

1. ca.pem
2. cert.pem
3. server-cert.pem

> Is is possible for me; with access to those files **ONLY**, not changing anything on the server, to access docker over TLS? How can I create my own **key.pem**, or is there another way?

---

*Sorry if this is common knowledge, I just could not find my answer anywhere, or I did not know what I was exactly searching for...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private keys create the certificates, you can't create a key from a cert. If your docker wants a 2 way authentication you will need access to the private key. It cannot be done without.

You'll need the following files (for client-server authentication):

1. ca.pem
2. cert.pem
3. key.pem

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can work against the docker-daemon on that server and you don't need to create another key and certificate for the server.

Download the `server-cert.pem` and export the following environment variables in your local session:

```
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
DOCKER_CERT_PATH="server-cert.pem"
DOCKER_HOST= "tcp://HOST:2376"
```

Now you can use your local docker-client and work against the docker-daemon on your server. e.g. `docker ps` should display containers running on the remote docker.

Comment: It's a 2 way authentication, so this won't work, the server won't accept.
The answer is as follows: 'It cannot be done'. The server administrator made a temporary folder where I can download the private key and delete it afterwards.